# Modify Flutter CupertinoPicker scroll to not continuously scroll?

Tags: flutter, cupertinopicker

Is there a way to modify CupertinoPicker scroll so that it's not possible to continuously scroll through a range. For example, right now if the range of values is 1-7, a user is able to continuously scroll 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ... Is there a way to modify CupertinoPicker to have the scroll stop at the 1 and 7 (in this use case), so that there isn't a continuous scroll?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Update: found it; there's a property called "looping" (boolean)

[image]

[image]